# AngularJS UI Bootstrap merge two progress bars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have set up two progress bars in UI Bootstrap, however my goal is to merge them into one, main bar and a secondary one which only is in the form of a vertical bar.

Here is the HTML code for my progress bars:

```
<div>
  <h3 class="inline-block no-margin">Main</h3>
  <uib-progressbar value="95"
                   class="progress-xs no-radius"
                   type="success"></uib-progressbar>
  <h4 class="no-margin">SubCategory</h4>
  <uib-progressbar value="50"
                   class="progress-xs no-radius no-margin"
                   type="danger"></uib-progressbar>
</div>
```

**My question** is how can I merge these two so that the secondary one only appears as a small vertical bar on the main bar?

So that the main bar showing 95% of the bar and the subcategory showing only a **vertical bar at 50%.**
[image]

There is an example similar to this in [here](http://bug7a.github.io/progressbar.js/) called limit lines, but it is another old library.

Comment: If I understand well, the goal of the second progress bar is to draw a vertical line on the first progress bar?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni yes, instead of having another progressbar, just a vertical bar, like a **|** that will move right and left according to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `ng-style` to update the position of a vertical line `div` in order to solve this problem. This will allow you to easily set the position and value of the vertical bar. Check out **[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/c9esZ6IWGFt8USKf9ZTn?p=preview)** working example on plunkr.:

**HTML**

```
<uib-progressbar animate="false" value=95 type="success"><b>95%</b></uib-progressbar>
<div id="vertical-mark" ng-style="style()">&nbsp;{{mark}}%</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.mark = 50;
  $scope.style = function() {
    return {
      'left': $scope.mark + '%'
    }
  }
```

**CSS**

```
#vertical-mark {
  position:relative;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  height:50px;
  top:-57px;
}
```

As an alternative I've also added a similar implementation with a stacked progress-bar.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this out on my own, but it's what came to mind when I saw your question.

You could modify the CSS of the ui-progressbars such that they were overlaid on one another; perhaps with an `position:absolute` or what have you. This would allow the numerical markers to all sit next to each other like you want.

Next, you could modify the CSS of the bars themselves. Any bars less than the max, perhaps give them a `.no-fill` class or something. It would be tricky, but that way you can have any bars less than max % to only consist of a `border-right` property, while the max % bar would be the one with the background and all the normal progress bar styles.

A gotcha that might show up is that you may also have to order the bars' `z-index` so that the largest value bar sits behind the lesser values and their vertical lines show up.

Good luck!

---

### FINAL UPDATE (with [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QWmK4LVDk5MRQJ5jsxDy?p=preview))

[image: plunkr screenshot]

#### JS

```
$scope.stacked = [{
  value: 55,
  type: 'info'
}, {
  value: 95,
  type: 'success'
}];
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <uib-progress max="100" ng-repeat="bar in stacked | orderBy:'value':true">
    <uib-bar value="bar.value" type="{{bar.type}}">
      <span class="marker" ng-hide="bar.value < 5">
          {{bar.value}}%
        </span>
    </uib-bar>
  </uib-progress>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* wrapper to help us contain the bars and their positioning */
.progress-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/* make all progress bars the same, no bg so they 'stack' */
.progress-wrapper .progress {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  background: none;
}

/* first child is the background bar, give it color */
.progress-wrapper .progress:first-child {
  background: #EEE;
}

/* make all bars invisible and with a right, border;
   except the last/furthest back bar, give it color only
*/
.progress-wrapper .progress .progress-bar {
  background: none;
  border-right: solid 2px #FFF;
}
.progress-wrapper .progress:first-child .progress-bar {
  background: #0AF;
  border-right: none;
}

/* makes sure that markers behave,
   otherwise they'll fly away
*/
.progress .progress-bar {
  position: relative;
}

/* style for marker element and drop triangle */
.progress .marker {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 2px;
  top: -30px;
  right: -15px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
}
.progress .marker:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  bottom: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want! could you make it with a vertical bar and a text message that will be displayed on that position as well. thanks

Comment: I don't really have the time right now to make it with the tag and everything that you had in the screenshots. I assumed that you already had some code that was working, you just wanted to have the bars stacked on top of each other. If you need a more complete solution I'll have to work on it after work, but the plunkr should get you or your ui dev closer to what you're after in the meanwhile. You also forgot to ask about my fee ;)

Comment: i will be waiting for your complete answer as soon as you have some time. let me know your fee as well!

Comment: There you go! I'd like to give credit to @bvakiti because I used their plunkr to get it started. It was just moving the repeat up one element, and adding all the appropriate CSS. no fee necessary :). happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of stacked progressbar with some custom styles.

```
<uib-progress><uib-bar ng-repeat="bar in stacked track by $index" value="bar.value" type="{{bar.type}}"><span ng-hide="bar.value < 5">{{bar.value}}%</span></uib-bar></uib-progress>

$scope.stacked = [{
  value: 10,
  type: 'info'
}, {
  value: 35,
  type: 'success'
}];
```

});

[image]

Refer progressbar in this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

My example is here https://plnkr.co/edit/9qCP1lV40BQ9DYDHvayo?p=preview

I have edited the code in stacked progressbar. Think this helps.

You can add custom styles to this to show the progress value.

Comment: Nice solution. Your plunkr link doesn't work though. Takes you to blank plunkr. Question: does the 10 and 35 get added here. It looks like that bar is about 45% wide. If the percents are something like 95 and 55, will this solution still work?

Comment: Yep, while elegant, this shows incorrect results when using large numbers. The stacked approach seems to only support multiple bars when sum of values is < 100%. If we use two or more that equal > 100, [the bars are not accurate](https://plnkr.co/edit/GABmToLK4uPCt8GDXxBg?p=preview).

Comment: Can you try giving max attribute to uib-progress. https://plnkr.co/edit/9qCP1lV40BQ9DYDHvayo?p=preview  Changing max value seems to work

Comment: this answer provides an alternative solution! if nobody gives a solution to use a vertical bar, then i will accept this. I don't mind any other solution that uses any other library or package.